# Почему Android Studio при запуске проекта не собирает приложение?

Tags: android, android-studio

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: после обновления Android Studio до версии "Arctic Fox" приложение перестало пересобираться при нажатии на кнопку Run (Shift+f10). То есть, если внести какие-то изменения в код проекта и запустить приложение на устройстве, приложение запускается, но изменений никаких не происходит. Приходится каждый раз чистить (clean project) и пересобирать проект (Rebuild project) вручную и только после этого запускать приложение.
Подскажите, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой уже?

Comment: После обновлений полезно чистить кэш, зачастую новая версия глючит с кешем от старой.

Comment: @woesss спасибо за помощь, но это не помогло..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот в чём была причина (Более опытный человек в программировании подсказал):
В конфигурации запуска почему-то отсутствовала команда сборки.
Как исправить:
В Android Studio выбираем Run -> edit configurations...
В открывшемся меню во вкладке General в самом низу будет выпадающее меню Before launch. Если в списке есть команда Gradle-aware Make - всё ок, проблема не в этом. Если же список пуст, нажимаем на "+" и в выпадающем меню "Add new task" выбираем Gradle-aware Make. Жмём "Apply" -> "Ok".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для тех у кого присутствует команда Gradle-aware Make, но все равно не запускается проект. Вот [инструкция](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66579530/error-the-apk-for-your-currently-selected-variant-unknown-output-is-not-signe) которая помогла мне запустить эмулятор у себя.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)